# Whats wrong with these SQL statements?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sql-server, count

Problem 1: Using the SQL CREATE TABLE statement, create a table, MOVSTARDIR, with attributes for the movie number, star number, and director number and the 4 acting awards. The primary key is the movie number, star number and director number (all 3), with referential integrity enforced. The director number is the director for that movie, and the star must have appeared in that movie. 
Load MOVSTARDIR (from existing tables) using INSERt INTO.

My answer:

```
CREATE TABLE MOVSTARDIR 
(MVNUM SHORT NOT NULL, STARNUM SHORT NOT NULL, DIRNUM SHORT NOT NULL, BESTF TEXT, BESTM       TEXT, SUPM TEXT, SUPF TEXT) 

ALTER TABLE MOVSTARDIR 
ADD PRIMARY KEY (MVNUM,STARNUM,DIRNUM) 

INSERT INTO MOVSTARDIR 
SELECT MOVIE.MVNUM,STAR.STARNUM,DIRECTOR.DIRNUM... BESTF,BESTM,SUPM,SUPF 
FROM MOVSTAR, DIRECTOR, MOVIE 
WHERE MOVSTAR.MVNUM=MOVIE.MVNUM 
AND MOVIE.DIRNUM=DIRECTOR.DIRNUM`
```

****Its giving me an error saying something is wrong with "create table" statement and it highlights the word "alter" in the SQL statement. Also how do i add referential integrity?****

Problem 2:List the directors in MOVSTARDIR with the total awards won from the 4 award categories included in the table. List the director name (not number), and the count in each of the 4 categories and the sum for all 4 categories. Group the report by the director name (i.e. one line per director, each director appears once), and order it by the sum (descending). Only show lines where the sum is more than 3.

```
SELECT DISTINCT DIRNAME, COUNT(BESTF) AS BESTFE, COUNT(BESTM) AS BESTML, 
COUNT(SUPM) AS SUPML, COUNT(SUPF) AS SUPFE, 
(COUNT(BESTM) COUNT(BESTF) COUNT(SUPM) COUNT(SUPF)) AS TOTAL 
FROM MOVSTARDIR, DIRECTOR 
WHERE MOVSTARDIR.DIRNUM=DIRECTOR.DIRNUM 
AND ((BESTM IS NOT NULL) OR (BESTF IS NOT NULL) OR (SUPM IS NOT NULL) 
OR (SUPF IS NOT NULL))  
GROUP BY DIRNAME 
HAVING (COUNT(BESTM) COUNT(BESTF) COUNT(SUPM) COUNT(SUPF)) 3 
ORDER BY (COUNT(BESTM) COUNT(BESTF) COUNT(SUPM) COUNT(SUPF))DESC`
```

****Problem with this is it list all records not just wins****
if the database is needed i can send the data base through email.

Answer (score 0):

**For Problem 1:**

If you are using mysql, the query for create should be as follows

```
CREATE TABLE  `MOVSTARDIR` (
`MVNUM` SMALLINT NOT NULL ,
`STARNUM` SMALLINT NOT NULL ,
`DIRNUM` SMALLINT NOT NULL ,
`BESTF` TEXT NOT NULL ,
`BESTM` TEXT NOT NULL ,
`SUPM` TEXT NOT NULL ,
`SUPF` TEXT NOT NULL
);
```

Comment: I am using Acess to do these problems not mysql

Comment: Up to my knowledge Access does not have any data type like Short try using Number instead. Link to data types http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms714540%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: when i just run this code CREATE TABLE MOVSTARDIR
(MVNUM SHORT NOT NULL, STARNUM SHORT NOT NULL, DIRNUM SHORT NOT NULL, BESTF TEXT, BESTM TEXT, SUPM TEXT, SUPF TEXT) It created the table without the rest of the code added. But when i put the Alter code then it gives me the error. I think something is wrong with the alter code.
ALTER TABLE MOVSTARDIR
ADD PRIMARY KEY (MVNUM,STARNUM,DIRNUM)

Answer (score 0):

You're missing the semicolon after each of the statements, causing Access to treat the entire text as one statement.

Answer (score 0):

1. Your tags show MySQL, SQL Server and SQL. The syntax of the SQL can vary according to the RDBMS.
2. Assuming you are using MySQL, these are the issues with your query.

   a. Data type - There is no SHORT in MySQL. You can use SMALLINT

   b. You need to add semi colons after each sql statement

Even if you are using any other RDBMS, you need to refer the corresponding SQL manual and verify that you specify the exact data types.

Answer (score 0):

Access doesn't allow to run a batch of queries, only one by one.
So, run first CREATE TABLE, then ALTER and so on.